# If $X \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$, what is the distribution of $Y=aX-b$?

Tags: distributions, self-study

Let $X \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$ and $Y=aX-b$. I want to find the distribution of $Y$.

I am assigned a homework problem with specific $a$ and $b$. My textbook covers methods for solving this, given that x is continuously distributed. However, $X$ is discretely distributed.

I'm not looking to be shown exactly how to do this. I am just unsure of where to start, as this is not covered in our text.

Any help you could provide to me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (i) What are the possible values that $y$ can take? if $x\in\{0,1\}$ then $y=ax+b\in\{...\}$. (ii) You know that $P(x=1)=p$ and $P(x=0)=1-p$ you can then prove that $x=(y+b)/a$, therefore $p=P(x=1)=P[(y+b)/a=1]$, similarly $1-p=P(x=0)=P[(y+b)/a=0]$ ... I hope these hints help.

Comment: @Procrastinator: Please consider converting your comment to an answer so that I may upvote (again).

Comment: @cardinal Thanks for the kind offer. I am not sure about converting the comment to an answer because the OP seems not to be really interested. But you can choose another answer to [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63439/186612) :P. See you in the next discussion (possibly about something in the boundary) :)

Comment: @Procrastinator: I empathize (strongly) with that sentiment. It's also helpful to keep in mind, as I'm sure you already do, that answers aren't only for the OP.

Comment: I thought that I had commented back on this. My apologies! Your comment did help me. I appreciate it!